# users/roles/permissions implementation using Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, user-permissions, custom-backend

I want to implement a backend system with Laravel 4.

Like any other CMS, it is required to be able to:

- Create Users
- Create Roles/Groups
- Assign Users to Roles/Groups
- Set Add/Edit/Delete permissions of modules to Roles/Groups

Is there any package/bundle available in Laravel 4 for above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at http://packalyst.com/ and search for the terms `authentication`, `authorization`, `roles`, etc.

It will give you an up to date overview of all the available packages as well as their popularity.

Here are a couple of popular ones according to the number of downloads:

- http://packalyst.com/packages/package/cartalyst/sentry
- http://packalyst.com/packages/package/zizaco/confide
- http://packalyst.com/packages/package/machuga/authority-l4

Comment: Thanks, I checked there. I found a package called 'Syntara'. It has already built small backend system with basic users, roles and permissions. I am wondering is there any other with a little more rich features for permissions control over generated CRUD modules.

Comment: I've added a list of the most popular ones in terms of downloads. You should definitely check out all three of them to start with as they are all feature rich and allow for fine grained permissions.